# Ruby gsub/regex to find all chars but not specific words

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-lookarounds

**My Objective:**
I have a string like so:

```
"O_1324||T_6789||EC_67889&&(IC_12345||chicken)||true&&false"
```

My dream is to use a gsub regex to identify `[a-zA-z0-9_]` and replace them with something ("false" if you must know). However I don't want to replace the words "true" or "false".

**What have I tried**
I have been using the super friendly [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) with little success.

I can get all the "words" (non operators) like so:
`(\w+)`

I tried matching all the "words" except "true" like so:
`(?!true)(\w+)`

This did not work. It unmatches only the "t" in true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following regex :

```
\b(?:(?!true|false)\b)\w+\b
```

see demo https://regex101.com/r/eX6rE6/1

Note that you need to use word boundary for matching words. and put the negative look-ahead before `\w+` not after!